# Pig Not Interpreting Int Correctly -- Custom Loader

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

So this is my first time to ever use Pig and I'm having a hard time getting it to interpret my data correctly.  I dont want to have to define a schema for my input files until run time, so I wrote a super simple custom loader where the only changes I made to PigStorage were changing the GetSchema Method to read the first two lines of my file and create a schema off of it:

```
public ResourceSchema getSchema(String location,
        Job job) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(location.replace("file://", "")));
    String[] line = br.readLine().split(",");
    String[] data = br.readLine().split(",");

    List<FieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<FieldSchema>();

    for(int f = 0; f< line.length; f++)
    {
        Byte type = GetType(data[f].replace("\"", ""));
        fields.add(new FieldSchema(line[f].replace("\"", ""), type));
    }

    schema = new ResourceSchema(new Schema(fields));
    return schema;
}

private Byte GetType(Object Data)
{
    try{
        int number = Integer.parseInt(Data.toString());
        return org.apache.pig.data.DataType.INTEGER;
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    try{
        double dnumber = Double.parseDouble(Data.toString());
        return org.apache.pig.data.DataType.DOUBLE;
    }
    catch(Exception e){}

    return org.apache.pig.data.DataType.CHARARRAY;
}
```

When I load a file and run DESCRIBE on it, it looks like what I want, for instance:

```
{CU_NUMBER: int,CYCLE_DATE: chararray,JOIN_NUMBER: int,RSSD: int,CU_TYPE: int,CU_NAME: chararray}
```

And the first 10 Rows look like this:

```
(1,9/30/2013 0:00:00,2,"50377","1","MORRIS SHEPPARD TEXARKANA")
(5,9/30/2013 0:00:00,6,"859879","1","FIRST CASTLE")
(6,9/30/2013 0:00:00,7,"54571","1","THE NEW ORLEANS FIREMEN'S")
(12,9/30/2013 0:00:00,11,"56678","1","FRANKLIN TRUST")
(13,9/30/2013 0:00:00,12,"861676","1","E")
(16,9/30/2013 0:00:00,14,"59277","1","WOODMEN")
(19,9/30/2013 0:00:00,16,"863773","1","NEW HAVEN TEACHERS")
(22,9/30/2013 0:00:00,17,"61074","1","WATERBURY CONNECTICUT TEACHER")
(26,9/30/2013 0:00:00,19,"866372","1","FARMERS")
(28,9/30/2013 0:00:00,21,"953375","1","CENTRIS")
```

However, when I try to do stuff with the data like:

```
FOICU = LOAD 'file:///home/biadmin/NCUA/foicu.txt' USING org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorageInferSchema(',', '-schema');
FirstSixColumns = FOREACH FOICU GENERATE CU_NUMBER, CYCLE_DATE, JOIN_NUMBER, RSSD, CU_TYPE, CU_NAME;
TopTen = LIMIT FirstSixColumns 10;
FOICUFiltered = FILTER TopTen BY CU_NUMBER > 20;
CU_FIVE = FILTER TopTen BY CU_NUMBER == 5;
DUMP FOICUFiltered;
DUMP CU_FIVE;
```

FOICUFiltered returns all 10 rows even though 7 of them have a CU_NUMBER less than 20:

```
(1,9/30/2013 0:00:00,2,"50377","1","MORRIS SHEPPARD TEXARKANA")
(5,9/30/2013 0:00:00,6,"859879","1","FIRST CASTLE")
(6,9/30/2013 0:00:00,7,"54571","1","THE NEW ORLEANS FIREMEN'S")
(12,9/30/2013 0:00:00,11,"56678","1","FRANKLIN TRUST")
(13,9/30/2013 0:00:00,12,"861676","1","E")
(16,9/30/2013 0:00:00,14,"59277","1","WOODMEN")
(19,9/30/2013 0:00:00,16,"863773","1","NEW HAVEN TEACHERS")
(22,9/30/2013 0:00:00,17,"61074","1","WATERBURY CONNECTICUT TEACHER")
(26,9/30/2013 0:00:00,19,"866372","1","FARMERS")
(28,9/30/2013 0:00:00,21,"953375","1","CENTRIS")
```

And CU_FIVE returns no rows at all.

Does anybody know what I've done wrong here and is there a better way to dynamically load the schema at run time without using schema files?